# OSX SL Server CalDav/DirectoryServices Authentication Error

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, osx-snow-leopard, caldav

I have a OSX SL Server (Version 10.6.8) that has been in production with about 40 users for approximately a year now.  Since day one I have had problems where occasionally a users iCal client throws authentication errors.  Resetting the users password solves the problem. I can either reset it for them or they can reset their own using the connect to server dialog.

Because the users can reset their own passwords and it accepts their old passwords for this purpose I feel the problem is probably iCal and not Open Directory. None of the workstations are joined/binded to the domain.

Additionally read proxies for conferences rooms and the delegation on our main company calendar showing is in and out gets lost. The read-proxies I have a shell script to recreate but adding everyone in the company as a delegate on the company calendar is a major pain as I cannot find a command line way to do this.

It seems like the occurrences have increased lately to a couple times a week. Its mostly different users although some have more problems than others. The latest one happened this afternoon and I tried to find relevant log files and entries. This is what I came up with. I am a Linux admin and this is my only OSX server so if there are better log files to be looking at please let me know.  I am not very familiar with OSX server.

/var/log/caldavd/error.log

```
2011-10-04 15:40:08-0500 [-] [caldav-8009]  [PooledMemCacheProtocol,client]              [twistedcaldav.directory.appleopendirectory.OpenDirectoryRecord#error] OpenDirectory  (node=/Search) error while performing digest authentication for user <my_user>: ('DirectoryServices Error: Exception raised in file src/CDirectoryService.cpp at line 1078', - 14002)
```

/Library/Logs/PasswordService/ApplePasswordServer.Server.log

```
Oct  4 2011 16:15:02    AUTH2: {0x4ca144cc5f7fd0790000002a0000002a, <my_user>} WEBDAV-DIGEST authentication failed, SASL error -13 (password incorrect).
```

After the password is reset by myself or the user this changes to

```
Oct  4 2011 16:15:42    AUTH2: {0x4ca144cc5f7fd0790000002a0000002a, <my_user>} WEBDAV-DIGEST authentication succeeded.
```

/Library/Logs/PasswordService/ApplePasswordServer.Error.log

```
Oct  4 2011 16:00:54    client response doesn't match what we generated
```

This is repeated many times but without any reference to which client.

Comment: I have the same problem on Lion server, no iCal server activated.

Lot of `client response doesn't match what we generated` messages

Comment: Sorry to say that, but I had no single good day with OSX servers. And it seems to be reality that neither apple nor ms are fit enough to implement RFC's. It may sound stupid, but I went for PHP driven DAViCal to have nights with sleep.

Comment: You should try the Console application in /Applications/Utilities/Console.app. It is basically a fancy gui version of unix tail but shows all the system logs at once so you can correlate log entries.

Comment: It has to do with apple's user directory. I have had this issue for years on both mountain lion and mavericks servers. Essentially what happens is that the directory service randomly denies user access usually stating something along the lines of permissions errors. It will literally work on minute and stop the next, then work again. This is why we're moving away from OS X Server.